# activemq - create new broker in servicemix/fuseesb

Tags: apache-camel, activemq-classic, apache-servicemix, fuseesb

I'm using fuseesb as my esb and i wanted to create new message broken in activemq, so i'm doing:

in karaf: `activemq:create-broker --name=myBroker`

then i see:

```
    Creating file: @|green .../myBroker-broker.xml|

Default ActiveMQ Broker (myBroker) configuration file created at: .../myBroker-broker.xml
Please review the configuration and modify to suite your needs.
```

i see that the file was created, but in karaf i see then:

```
karaf@root> Exception in thread "SpringOsgiExtenderThread-26" java.lang.IllegalStateException: BeanFactory not initialized or already closed - call 'refresh' before accessing beans via the ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.getBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:171)
    at org.springframework.osgi.context.support.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext$4.run(AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.java:368)
    at org.springframework.osgi.util.internal.PrivilegedUtils.executeWithCustomTCCL(PrivilegedUtils.java:85)
    at org.springframework.osgi.context.support.AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.completeRefresh(AbstractDelegatedExecutionApplicationContext.java:320)
    at org.springframework.osgi.extender.internal.dependencies.startup.DependencyWaiterApplicationContextExecutor$CompleteRefreshTask.run(DependencyWaiterApplicationContextExecutor.java:132)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
```

And i don't know what it is...

Could you help me?

Comment: This looks like a possible bug.  Can you please add the versions of Karaf and ActiveMQ you are using and if you used a feature, the URI that you used?  Also, if you were using a feature, what ones did you load?  Thanks, Scott ES

Comment: I'm using  Apache ServiceMix v4.4.1-fuse-06-03

Answer (score 1):

I had the same exception and fixed it by changing the configured ports in my newly-generated broker xml file so they didn't clash with the default broker, which is configured in etc/activemq-broker.xml

Comment: http://www.andrejkoelewijn.com/wp/2010/11/09/adding-an-activemq-broker-in-servicemix/